# how to put MySQL path in bash profile

Tags: macos, bash

I have to alter the bash profile in my mac in order to configure MYSQL but I don't know how to access the bash profile. The operating system of my mac was just replaced and the bash profile is no longer visible (it was visible but ghosted before). I'm using Mac 10.6.8 leopard (not lion)

Anyone know how I can get the path in my bash profile?  I would also like a way to make the bash profile visible so I can open it anytime with a text editor.

Comment: if you're voting to close this, as some have, can you please explain why?

Comment: Is there a Mac tag?  This really isn't so much a bash question as a bash related question.

Comment: GOTO http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it's a question about how to get information into the bash profile...beginnner yes, but it's still a bash question. I'll add a mac tag

Comment: When you say "visible but ghosted before", that leads me to think you're looking at it from Finder or some other GUI. If you open up Terminal and type `ls -lrt ~/.profile`, what do you see?

Comment: @Ben Hocking  I want it to be visible but ghosted, i.e. so I can see it in the Finder...There's something you can do to make the invisible files visible..when I type in the command you recommend, it says no such file. However, there is a bash profile

Comment: @mjmitche: I should've added a "-a", so that the command would be `ls -lart ~/.profile`. I'm mostly a command-line kinda guy, but files beginning with a "." are considered "hidden" (which is why you need the "-a" flag). Now that I think I understand your problem, I'm preparing a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're no longer showing hidden files (i.e., files beginning with a "."). To fix that, open up a Terminal prompt, and type the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

After that, you'll want to either reboot (not a bad idea if you haven't rebooted in awhile, in my opinion), or type:

```
killall Finder
```

To reset this option, just replace `TRUE` with `FALSE`.